# Gtk thread blocking function execution?

Tags: python, multithreading, gtk, shared-libraries

I have the following python code:

```py
import threading
from fpysensor import fp
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Hello, World!")
        self.set_border_width(10)
        
        label = Gtk.Label()
        label.set_label("Hello, World!")
        self.add(label)

def run():
    win = MainWindow()
    win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
    win.show_all()
    Gtk.main()

threading.Thread(target=run).start()
threading.Thread(target=fp.run_verification, args=("127.0.0.1", 5000)).start()

while True:
    pass
```

`fp` module is defined as:

```py
from fpysensor import __fingerprint
from ctypes import c_char_p

def run_enrollment(ip_addr: str, port: int): 
    """
    Run the fingerprint enrollment process
    """

    __ip_cp = c_char_p(ip_addr.encode('utf-8'))
    __fingerprint.py_run_enrollment(__ip_cp, port)
def run_verification(ip_addr: str, port: int):
    """
    Run verification against the fingerprints stored
    """
    __ip_cp = c_char_p(ip_addr.encode('utf-8'))
    __fingerprint.py_run_verification(__ip_cp, port)
```

Where

```py
__fingerprint = ctypes.CDLL(f"{__wd}/lib.so")
```

As you can see, I'm using a shared library name `lib.so` ([Code here](https://gitlab.com/parawa/fingerprint)) and calling that library with the functions defined on fp. Now for some reason, when I'm running gtk, even on a different thread, my function, in this case `fp.run_verification` isn't executed until I close the window created by gtk on `MainWindow` class. Is gtk blocking all threads or there's something wrong with my C library?

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a call to [Gdk.threads_init()](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gdk-3.0/functions.html#Gdk.threads_init) before you start your threads to allow GTK to release the GIL, so your other python functions can run.

also the busy loop here is wrong, it will slow down your application significantly, consider running the GUI in the main thread or `join()` the thread running the GUI after your start the second thread.